# Dax - Creating Column That Checks Dates Sequence

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have im my model table that contains data from reports based on monthly reporting of employees with column names "ReportDate" and enployye numbers.
I want to check that there is no gaps between the monthly dates to each employee with DAX.

For example:

**EmpNum | ReportDate | CheckColumn**

111 | 30.08.2019

111 | 30.09.2019

111 | 31.10.2019

222 | 30.08.2019

222| 31.10.2019 ----------> Here I want alert in my CheckColumn

Can someone find me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a index column. Go to `Edit Queries > Add Column > Index Column`, starting with 1 for example.

Next you add a column with DAX which has a shift of 1 to the original column with this expression (make sure this column is from the same date format as your original column; `Modelling > Format`):

```
ShiftColumn = DATEVALUE(CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Report Date]);FILTER('Table';'Table'[Index]=EARLIER('Table'[Index])-1)))
```

Next add the column with the check:

```
Column 2 = IF(DATEADD('Table'[Report Date].[Date];-1;DAY) = 'Table'[ShiftColumn]; TRUE(); FALSE())
```

The result:

[image]